# MongoDB find subdocument ids

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-query

I have my schema setup this way:

```
{
 _id:1234,
 friends: [
           {
             "fid":1235
             "is_user":true
           },
           {
             "fid":1236
             "is_user":true
           },
           {
             "fid":1235
             "is_user":false
           }
          ]
 }
```

My requirement is that, given a `_id`, I need to find all the friend ids `(fid)` who have `is_user` set to true.

I tried the following :

```
db.users.find({ friends: { $elemMatch : { is_app_user: true}}});
```

seems to give me back results in the whole collection, but I want it for an ID. so I tried this:

```
db.users.find({_id:1234},{friends: { $elemMatch : { is_app_user: true}}});
```

but that gave me nothing. Also, all I need back is the `fid` . Can somebody help me out with this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a case like this where you want more than just the *first* matching element from the array, you have to use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) instead of a `find`.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    // Find the matching document
    { $match: { _id: 1234 }},
    // Duplicate the document for each element of friends
    { $unwind: '$friends' },
    // Filter the documents to just those where friends.is_user = true
    { $match: { 'friends.is_user': true }},
    // Only include fid in the results
    { $project: { _id: 0, fid: '$friends.fid'}}
]);
```

Comment: Thank you JohnnyHK .. (and Chris :) )